# Looping function with left_join over multiple variables

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, left-join, mapply

I am working to loop a function that contains a left_join iteratively over a dataframe based on multiple variables in R. The function works when I run it line-by-line over the dataframe, but breaks down in the loop. I need to automate this process because I have to run it hundreds of times, but I am getting errors using foreach and mapply.

A portion of the original data set and the original function is this:

```
 library(tidyverse)  
    ID <- c(22226820,22226820,22226814,22226814)
        ID_US_1 <- c(22226830,22226818,22226816,22226832)
        mydf <- data.frame(cbind(ID==as.character(ID),ID_US_1=as.character(ID_US_1)))
        
        
        ID_key <- c(22226830,22226818,22226818,22226816,22226816,22226832,22226832,22226806,22226806,22226814,22226814,22226804)
        ID_key_US <- c(0,22226806,22226814,22226804,22226802,22226840,22226842,22226798,22226796,22226816,22226832,22227684)
        
        mykey <- data.frame(cbind(ID_key=as.character(ID_key),ID_key_US=as.character(ID_key_US)))
        
        
        myfx <- function(iteration_prior,iteration){
          # iteration_prior <- "1"
          #  iteration <- "2"
          varnameprior <- paste0("ID_US","_",iteration_prior)
          varname <- paste0("ID_US","_",iteration)
          
          colnames(mykey) <- c(varnameprior,varname)
          
          mydf <-mydf %>% 
                left_join(x=.,y=mykey,by=varnameprior)  
         
          mydf[,ncol(mydf)][is.na(mydf[,ncol(mydf)])] <- 0
          mydf[,ncol(mydf)]<-as.character(mydf[,ncol(mydf)])
        
          
          return(mydf)
        }
        
        prior <- c(1,2,3)
        current <- c(2,3,4)
        mylist <- data.frame(cbind(prior=prior,current=current))
        
        mydf <- myfx(prior[1],current[1])
        mydf <- myfx(prior[2],current[2])
```

This creates my desired output, which is iterative columns of data. ID_US_2 is calculated based on ID_US_1 using the mykey dataframe and ID_US_3 is calculated using ID_US_2 and mykey.

I need to carry out this operation hundreds of times, which means I need to automate the process. I have tried a foreach loop and get the error that 'Join columns must be present in data'. I think this means my new output is not correctly amending to the dataframe. I got the same error/issue with mapply.

```
    library(foreach)  
    foreach(i=prior,j=current) %do% {myfx(i,j)}
```

I also considered a nested for loop, but was hung up on the multiple variables (and foreach/mapply seem better suited).

Comment: Trying to parallelize an operation that depends on the prior iteration is destined to fail. You will either have to remove that dependence or run it with a standard loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your only issue is that you haven't reassigned mydf in the foreach command. Editing that, you have:

```
foreach(i=prior, j=current) %do% {mydf <- myfx(i,j)}
```